# how to call the index of a listview outside of builder in flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, indexing, builder

I'm assigning an icon with a .removeAt outside the listview.builder, I think the problem is calling the index, how can I call the index outside the listview builder? please help, here's a sample of my code:

```
    newList(){
    return new ListView.builder(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: newRoutineList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return newRoutineList[index];
              });
  }
```

[image]

and here's the function outside the listview.builder where I'm creating an Icon for .removeAt

```
new Container(
                              width: 70,
                              alignment: Alignment(0.5, 1),
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  newRoutineList.removeAt(index);
                                },
                              ),
                            )
```

[image]

Comment: which item do you want to remove ?

Comment: the index of newRoutineList[index] which is declared globally as 
List<Widget> newRoutineList = [];

Comment: yes but which index(the 1st, 2nd ????)  you want to remove, it has to be known isn't it ?

Comment: it's supposed to be dynamically, but I don't know how to do it, I can create new items but I don't know how to delete it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. If can also use Map instead of List

```
List newRoutineList = new List();
@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 newRoutineList.add("A");
 newRoutineList.add("B");
 newRoutineList.add("C");
 newRoutineList.add("D");
 newRoutineList.add("E");
}

Widget newList() {
 return new ListView.builder(
    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: newRoutineList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        width: 70,
        alignment: Alignment(0.5, 1),
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              newRoutineList.removeAt(index);
            });
          },
        ),
      );
    });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: newList());
}
```